# SQL GROUP BY and retrieve last child records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm writing a DB view that pulls data from several tables. The goal is to determine the latest status of a company, and this is noted by each record (grouped by company_id) with the highest `vetting_event_type_position`.

Essentially I'm trying to grab the latest record for each company. I'm not a SQL guru at all; I understand I need to `group by` in order to collapse the related records, but I can't get that to work.

**Current results**

```
company_id | name | ... | vetting_event_type_position
-----------------------------------------------------
         1 | ABC  | ... |                          1 
         1 | ABC  | ... |                          2 
         1 | ABC  | ... |                          3 
         2 | CBS  | ... |                          1 
         2 | CBS  | ... |                          2 
         3 | HBO  | ... |                          1
```

**DESIRED results**

```
company_id | name | ... | vetting_event_type_position
-----------------------------------------------------
         1 | ABC  | ... |                          3 
         2 | CBS  | ... |                          2 
         3 | HBO  | ... |                          1
```

**SQL Code**

```
SELECT
    companies.id as company_id,
    companies.name as name,
    companies.uuid as uuid,
    companies.company_type as company_type,
    companies.description as overview,
    practice_areas.id as practice_area_id,
    practice_areas.name as practice_area_name,
    companies.created_at as created_at,
    companies.updated_at as updated_at,
    companies.created_by as created_by,
    companies.updated_by as updated_by,
    vettings.id as vetting_id,
    vettings.name as vetting_name,
    vetting_event_types.name as vetting_event_status,
    vetting_events.id as vetting_event_id,
    vetting_event_types.position as vetting_event_type_position
FROM
    vettings
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vetting_events ON (vettings.id = vetting_events.vetting_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vetting_event_types ON (vetting_events.vetting_event_type_id = vetting_event_types.id)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN companies ON (companies.id = vettings.company_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN practice_areas ON (companies.practice_area_id = practice_areas.id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dispositions ON (companies.disposition_id = dispositions.id)
ORDER BY
    name, vetting_name, vetting_event_type_position
;
```

**Associations among tables**

```
companies      has_many   vettings
vettings       has_many   vetting_events
vetting_events belongs_to vetting_event_types
```

or put another way...

```
companies -> vettings -> vetting_events <- vetting_event_types
```

I am trying to retrieve the company record with the highest `vetting_event_types.position` value for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT company_id
      ,name
      ,uuid
      ,company_type
      ,overview
      ,practice_area_id
      ,practice_area_name
      ,created_at
      ,created_by
      ,updated_by
      ,vetting_id
      ,vetting_name
      ,vetting_event_status
      ,vetting_event_id
      ,vetting_event_type_position
FROM (
     SELECT
    companies.id as company_id,
    companies.name as name,
    companies.uuid as uuid,
    companies.company_type as company_type,
    companies.description as overview,
    practice_areas.id as practice_area_id,
    practice_areas.name as practice_area_name,
    companies.created_at as created_at,
    companies.updated_at as updated_at,
    companies.created_by as created_by,
    companies.updated_by as updated_by,
    vettings.id as vetting_id,
    vettings.name as vetting_name,
    vetting_event_types.name as vetting_event_status,
    vetting_events.id as vetting_event_id,
    vetting_event_types.position as vetting_event_type_position,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY companies.id ORDER BY vetting_event_types.position DESC) rn

    FROM vettings
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vetting_events ON (vettings.id = vetting_events.vetting_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN vetting_event_types ON (vetting_events.vetting_event_type_id = vetting_event_types.id)
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN companies ON (companies.id = vettings.company_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN practice_areas ON (companies.practice_area_id = practice_areas.id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dispositions ON (companies.disposition_id = dispositions.id)
     ) A
WHERE A.rn = 1
ORDER BY name, vetting_name, vetting_event_type_position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number analytic function.

```
Select * from (
    Select ...,
    Row_number() over ( partition by    company_id order by     vetting_event_type_position desc) as seq) T
 Where seq=1
```